# Trying to open a popup on clicking the text in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i' want to make the given link (`<td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status) </td>`) a hyperlink in mvc where data is coming from database dynamically.
And also on clicking this text a popup should be opened .
Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not open popup by clicking on @html.displayfor but you can use this method for open popup.

put @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status) in the 'div'or 'span' and give them unique id

**Eaxmple:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#displayfor").click(function(){
       alert('message !..or use can use popup here');
    });
  
   $("#span").click(function(){
        alert('message !..or use can use popup here');
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
    <div id="displayfor">
  <h5>Click on <br>
    "@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status)" </h5>
     </div>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  <span id="span">
   <h5>Click on  <br>
     "@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status)" </h5> 
  

  </span>
  
  
  </html>
```